# AS3 Increment Timer by User Input

Tags: actionscript-3

I am a noob to AS3 so excuse me, please.

I have a timer on my app that I am trying to use as a stop watch, What I would like to do is start it at a specified time not always at 0?

I would like the user to enter in a text box a value of 1 to 99 and the timer starts from there entered value.

Thanks in advance.

```
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;

var customtime:int;
clock.text = "00:00";
var myTimer:Timer = new Timer(1000,0);
myTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, stopwatch);

function stopwatch(event:TimerEvent):void
{

    clock.text = convert_time(myTimer.currentCount);

}

start_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startClock);
stop_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopClock);
reset_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, resetClock);
setTime_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setCustomTime);

function startClock(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimer.start();
}

function stopClock(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimer.stop();
}

function resetClock(evt:MouseEvent):void
{
    myTimer.reset();
    clock.text = "00:00";
}

function setCustomTime(evt:MouseEvent)
{
        var t1:int = int(setTimeTxt.text)*60;
        clock.text = convert_time(t1);
        customtime = t1;
}


function time_update(t1:int):int
{
    var t2:int=t1*60;
    return t2;
}

function convert_time(currentAmountSecs:int):String
{
    var minutes:int = Math.floor(currentAmountSecs / 60);
    var seconds:int = currentAmountSecs % 60;

    var prependString:String = "";
    if ( minutes < 10 )
    {
        prependString = "0";
    }

    var prependStringsec:String = "";
    if ( seconds < 10 )
    {
        prependStringsec = "0";
    }

    return prependString + minutes + ":" + prependStringsec + seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can't change `Timer/currentCount` but you can store a start count and display `startCount + myTimer.currentCount`:

```
var startCount:int = 100; 

clock.text = convert_time(startCount + myTimer.currentCount);
```

As for how to determine the `startCount` from a user text input: you can use `parseInt` to convert text to an integer. You should also restrict the text input to numbers, and you can enforce a range of 0-99 using `Math.min` and `Math.max`:

```
// restrict input characters to numbers
input.restrict = "0-9";

// update the `startCount` any time user input changes
input.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE, inputChange);
function inputChange(e:Event):void {

    // parse an integer from the text input
    startCount = parseInt(input.text);

    // limit the range to 0-99
    startCount = Math.max(0, Math.min(startCount, 99));

    // make sure the input text displays the in-range value
    if (input.text != String(startCount)) 
        input.text = String(startCount);
}
```

Comment: The time was not added this line did not do anything:  var startTime:int = 100; 

clock.text = convert_time(startTime + myTimer.currentCount);

Comment: I assure you it does, you must be testing it wrongly. For example when I run that code I get `01:40`, if I change `var startTime:int = 200` I get `03:20`.

Comment: (For clarity I just renamed `startTime` to `startCount` in my example code.)

Comment: @Dami1, this is a correct answer. Ofcourse the time won't increase until you do `myTimer.start();` and you must use `clock.text = convert_time(startCount + myTimer.currentCount);` in your function called **function stopwatch**, Anyways your **customtime**  is same thing as **startCount** in this answer...